# react-markdown - bold after slash

Tags: reactjs, react-markdown

So this does not work for me

```
<ReactMarkdown>{'**test/**test'}</ReactMarkdown>
```

However, this does

```
<ReactMarkdown>{'**test/test**test'}</ReactMarkdown>
```

It seems that the double asterisk doesn't work directly after `/`.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `<ReactMarkdown>{'**test\/**test'}</ReactMarkdown>`?

Comment: doesn't work...